# How to control time with API testing?

Tags: testing, api, time, functional-testing

I'm trying to test an API (see [API testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_testing)).

Some operations depend on time.
Here are some examples:

- A post may only be edited within the first 5 minutes
- You may not try to login more than 10 times in 1 minute
- After X weeks of inactivity a post is archived and set as read-only

If I'm testing from an external point of view, how can I manage time (moving it forward)?

One possible solution, for example using docker, is installing some interceptor to requests to the system clock. Are there other alternatives I'm not seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by "from an external point of view"?

Comment: @Flater Blackbox testing of an API. Testing as if you didn't know the implementation details of the API and therefore not being able to mock or change them.

Comment: There is a contradiction between your question (how to control the clock) and your explanation of blackbox testing (not being able to mock/change implementation). I've already written up an answer to address both black and white box testing.

Comment: @Flater Well, for example simulating the system clock would not "change implementation details of the API" but change the system the API runs on.

Comment: Using the system clock is an implementation detail. Knowing that the system clock is being used _is_ knowing an implementation detail.

Comment: @Flater That's true. But following the exact definition makes blackbox testing basically impossible (it's possible as you said by waiting X amount of time but that's reasonably impossible when you have to wait days and you only have 1 hour to verify that your code works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### White-box testing

This is why I usually implement an `IClock` interface in my logic, instead of directly depending on system time (e.g. `DateTime.Now`).

```
public interface IClock
{
    DateTime GetTime();
}
```

Your logic should depend on this clock:

```
public class FooManager
{
    private readonly IClock _clock;

    // Inject via constructor

    public bool CanPostBeEdited()
    {
        var now = _clock.GetTime();
    } 
}
```

Which allows you to test your logic by changing the clock, e.g.:

```
public class MockClock : IClock
{
    private DateTime _time;

    public void SetTime(DateTime time) { _time = time };

    public DateTime GetTime() => _time;
}


var clock = new MockedClock();

var fooManager = new FooManager(clock);

clock.SetTime("12:00") // using strings here for easy readability

// create post logic (which will also rely on that same clock)

clock.SetTime("12:04");
Assert.IsTrue(fooManager.CanPostBeEdited();

clock.SetTime("12:06");
Assert.IsFalse(fooManager.CanPostBeEdited();
```

*Note: This is pseudocode, I glossed over some technical details that didn't matter for the current context.*

---

### Black-box testing

If you're black-box testing, then you shouldn't have control over the internals of the API, which also includes not being able to tamper with the clock. You can't even know that it relies on a clock to begin with!

> One possible solution, for example using docker, is installing some interceptor to requests to the system clock.

If this was a proper black-box test, how would you even know that it relies on the system clock, as opposed to e.g. fetching the current time from an online service?

You're trying to focus your tests intelligently, but this requires knowing the internals, which is the antithesis of what black-box testing is.

In black-box testing, you test the API **as is**. I.e. you actually wait the required amount of time, along the lines of:

```
// create post

// actually wait 4 minutes
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));

// confirm that you can edit the post
Assert.IsTrue(myApi.CanPostBeEdited();

// actually wait 2 minutes
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

// confirm that you cannot edit the post
Assert.IsFalse(myApi.CanPostBeEdited();
```

*Note: This is pseudocode, I glossed over some technical details that didn't matter for the current context.*

---

### Keeping it real

> But following the exact definition makes blackbox testing basically impossible (it's possible as you said by waiting X amount of time but that's reasonably impossible when you have to wait days and you only have 1 hour to verify that your code works)

While I agree with you, I quickly want to point out that *"you only have 1 hour to verify that your code works"* is putting the cart before the horse. Tests take as long as they need to take. Ideally it takes less time, but if you start working with an arbitrary hard cap, then the issues that come from dealing with that cap are issues of your own making.

I do agree with you here, perfect black box testing can be cumbersome and practically impossible. You would otherwise only be able to test your leap-year-resistant logic once every 4 years (at best).

This is where you need to consider **properly defining the box you're testing**. If you make it an explicit requirement that the API *must* use the system clock, then the system clock is not an implementation detail.

If the system clock is not an implementation detail but an external dependency, then you can change the clock as you see fit. Similarly, if the database isn't part of the API (e.g. you're writing an API that reads from a pre-existing database that your API does not manage itself), then you get to mock and rewrite your database as you see fit.

Anything that's an external dependency and has been explicitly required by the specs is inherently not an implementation detail. You cannot move away from this dependency without then violating the specs, so you can be secure in knowing that e.g. the system time **will** be relied upon by your API. This puts it outside of the black box and loosens the restraints on whether you get to emulate it or not.

Comment: What's the highest level alternative to API testing? Integration tests?

Comment: @ShoeDiamente: It's not really an _alternative_ in the sense that one doesn't replace the other. Different tests have different purposes. Unit tests test your components, integration tests test your components' interactions with each other. "API test" is vague, as it could be construed as a unit test of the controllers to see that they route the requests correctly to the BLL (and nothing more), or a full integration test down to the database.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to avoid using statics ie DateTime.Now in your code. Always pass in properties like time.

This allows you to pass in arbitrary dates, in the future or past for testing or other edge case requirements like import/export.

eg

```
public AddPost(Post p)
{
    //archive if older that 2 weeks
    if(p.date < archiveDate) { ... }

}
```

NOT

```
public AddPost(Post p)
{
    //archive if older that 2 weeks
    if(DateTime.UtcNow < archiveDate) { ... }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but API testing has no access to the internal code. That would be integration or unit testing.

Comment: @ShoeDiamente From the first sentence of the Wikipedia page you linked to: "API testing is [...] part of integration testing".

Comment: if the code checks its own system clock, then your test just has to wait 10 days

Answer (score 0):

The best way (after having tried at least four different ones) is [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130862/96588): pass a `Clock` object or `now` function to the relevant entrypoint and manipulate that in the test. In pseudo-Python, your test would look something like this:

```
def function_under_test(foo, bar, clock):
    if foo.created < clock.now() + timedelta(days=7):
        frobnicate(foo)
```

Your test would then look like this:

```
def test_should_frobnicate_foo_if_more_than_a_week_old(self):
    clock = StaticClock(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1))
    foo = Foo(clock)  # Sets the creation date to clock.now()
    function_under_test(foo)

    self.assertTrue(foo.frobnicated)
```

If you *have* to black-box test something like this and you're not allowed to change it, you're in trouble. You could try introducing an otherwise redundant configuration variable, passing a "secret" parameter, detecting that the system is being tested, or actually leaving your tests to run for more than a week, but all of those are far from ideal.

Comment: I'm sorry but API testing has no access to the internal code. That would be integration or unit testing.

Comment: Well, then the only way to move time forward is the good old-fashioned way. I'm simply saying unit testing is by far the best way of doing this.

Comment: @l0b0: There is no "best way" or even "better" between unit, integration and user acceptance tests. They serve different purposes and one does cover the purpose of the other. I agree with you that unit tests are advised here - but that doesn't mean that other tests become obsolete just because you have unit tests.

Comment: @Flater Oh, I never intended to say that other tests are useless, only that if it is at all possible to write a unit test for the task at hand, it is preferable to integration or acceptance level tests.

Comment: @l0b0: I still disagree that the existence of a unit test would absolve the need for a similar integration or UA test. Just because the developer claims to have tested it (= unit test) doesn't meant that the end user shouldn't verify it (= UA test).

Comment: @Flater Writing one-to-one unit and acceptance tests is quickly going to make the test suite take several days to run, and makes half the tests redundant. Instead, acceptance tests should verify the overall functionality (for example, the various ways of calling an API endpoint) while unit tests verify the details.